# Table_calendar not show event indicator and event when data load

Tags: flutter, calendar, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have load data in init state but the event indicator does not show and when I click on other date and come bak data gone.

[Here is my code file](https://github.com/JasminScalelot/Questions/blob/main/TableEventsExample)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since `initState` is not `async`, you normally wouldn't add code to it that executes asynchronously (like a `fetch` of data). Instead, I would suggest using a `FutureBuilder` (or `StreamBuilder.periodic` if you want to keep fetching your data periodically).

Say you have the function

```dart
Future<List<Event>> fetchEvents() async {
  ...
  return events;
}
```

Which fetches the events from your local or online database and returns them as a list. You could then wrap your widget in a `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<Event>>(
  future: fetchEvents,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Event>> snapshot) {
    List<Event> events = snapshot.data ?? [];
    return MyAwesomeCalendarWidget(events: events);
  }
);
```

This way, the Widget will build first with the empty `List` (no events fetched yet), showing you an empty calendar, and once the data is fetched it'll rebuild accordingly. You would no longer need to use a `StatefulWidget` in this case.

Comment: Event list is Date wise so this not works And if you have idea can you please try that with my code

Answer (score 0):

```
eventLoader: (day) {
  for (var i = 0; i < listtasks.length; i++) {
    if (day == listtasks[i].date) {
         return [listtasks[i]];
     }
            }
            return [];
          },
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck